# Creating classes to represent different permutations of a type

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have a class structure like (simplifying the actual classes I have):

```
class Graph
{
};

class DerivedGraph : public Graph
{
};

class DerivedGraph2 : public Graph
{
};
```

I want to expand this structure to account for different variations of the same graph. Ideally I would like to be able to do something like:

```
class Graph
{
};

// Removed
//class DerivedGraph : public Graph
//{
//};

// Removed
//class DerivedGraph2 : public Graph
//{
//};

class DerivedGraph3 : public Graph // really just a mode of DerivedGraph
{
};

class DerivedGraph4 : public Graph // really just a second mode of DerivedGraph
{
};


class DerivedGraph5 : public Graph // really just a mode of DerivedGraph2
{
};

class DerivedGraph6 : public Graph // really just a second mode of DerivedGraph2
{
};
```

But you can quickly see the problem here -- I am having to create too many classes here. Also, the base class is extremely complex and large (the bottom line is that it just plain sucks) ... so I don't want to make too many structural changes. I want the flexibility of defining things at the level of just the graph itself but at the same time have the flexibility of defining things for a particular mode of one graph type. I would like to be able to use virtual functions such as DoesGraphSupportNormalizedData() or something like that (this is just a simple example). Each class would then override this method.

Another idea I had was to create a separate class structure for the modes themselves (the Graph class would create an instance of it), like:

```
class BaseMode
{
};

class Mode1 : public BaseMode
{
};

class Mode2 : public BaseMode
{
};
```

Now the problem is that these mode classes need access to several pieces of data from the Graph class ... and I really don't want to pass all of that information. The mode class would then become just as useless and wouldn't be flexible at all. I just can't think of a clean way to deal with this. The best I could come up with is to have the mode classes do what it can without having to pass all kinds of crap to it but now the interface is just goofy and awkward. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. All you describe just screams "use inheritance". I'm afraid without knowing more about the actual implementation of modes it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can either user and interface or use inherited classes from what I can gather from your description.

If you use a base-class and inherit off of it just have the things you don't want derived classes to have just give them the `private` access modifier and then `protected` or `public` for the others (depending on the situation of course). That way your derived classes only take what information they need. You could also have a instance variable that needs to be set in each of lower classes to define things about each derived class. Access modifiers are your friends.

If you use an interface just include everything each graph will need and then when building the individual classes just customize them from there to include the specialties.

If it were up to me, personally, I would go with inheritance over an interface but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in this kind of a problem before (and still now and then...)

In this case, you may be taking it the wrong way, what you're looking into is device a specialized function depending on the type of graph and mode. Inheritance is nice, but it has its limits as you mentioned. Especially because the user may want to switch the type of graph, but keep is existing graph object. Inheritance is not helpful in that case.

One way to do something like this is to create functions that get called depending on the current type and mode. Say you have to draw lines and the mode can be set to LINE or DOTS. You could have two functions that draw a line and are specific to a mode or another:

```
void Graph::draw_line_line(line l)
{
    // draw a line
}

void Graph::draw_line_dots(line l)
{
    // draw a dots along the line
}
```

Now you can define a type which represents that type of render functions and a variable member for it:

```
typedef void (Graph::*draw_line_func)(line l);

draw_line_func    m_draw_line;
```

With that in hands, you can program your set_mode() function, something like this:

```
void Graph::set_mode(mode_t mode)
{
    m_mode = mode; // save for get_mode() to work
    switch(mode)
    {
    case LINE:
        m_draw_line = &Draw::draw_line_line;
        break;

    case DOTS:
        m_draw_line = &Draw::draw_line_dots;
        break;

    ...
    }
}
```

Now when you want to render the line, you do call this specialized function and you do not need to know whether it is a LINE or a DOTS...

```
void Graph::draw_line(line l)
{
    this->*m_draw_line(l);
}
```

This way you create an indirection and make it a lot cleaner in the existing large functions that have large switch or many if() statements without breaking up the existing "powerful" class in many pieces that may become hard to use (because if it's that big it's probably already in use...)